# How to animate circular progress bar on page scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a circular progress bar that animates when the page loads, but I want it to animate when the user scrolls down to it, as it will be in the middle of the page. Right now if the page loads, the user does not see the animation.

So essentially, the animation should be paused until the user scrolls down to a certain point, once the bar is in view, the animation starts.

I used this jquery plugin https://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/jQuery-Plugin-SVG-Progress-Circle.html

```
function makesvg(percentage, inner_text = "") {
    var abs_percentage = Math.abs(percentage).toString();
    var percentage_str = percentage.toString();
    var classes = ""
    if (percentage < 0) {
        classes = "danger-stroke circle-chart__circle--negative";
    } else if (percentage > 0 && percentage <= 30) {
        classes = "warning-stroke";
    } else {
        classes = "success-stroke";
    }
    var svg = '<svg class="circle-chart" viewbox="0 0 33.83098862 33.83098862" 
    xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" > ' +
    '<circle class="circle-chart__background" cx="16.9" cy="16.9" r="15.9"  / >
    ' +
    '<circle class="circle-chart__circle ' + classes + '"' +
        'stroke-dasharray="' + abs_percentage + ',100"    cx="16.9" cy="16.9" 
    r = "15.9" / > ' +
    '<g class="circle-chart__info">' +
    '   <text style="color:#fff;" class="circle-chart__percent" x="17.9" 
    y = "15.5" > '+percentage_str+' % < /text>';
    if (inner_text) {
        svg += '<text class="circle-chart__subline" x="16.91549431" 
        y = "22" > '+inner_text+' < /text>'
    }
    svg += ' </g></svg>';
    return svg
}

(function($) {
    $.fn.circlechart = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            var percentage = $(this).data("percentage");
            var inner_text = $(this).text();
            var inner_text2 = $(this).text();
            $(this).html(makesvg(percentage, inner_text));
        });
        return this;
    };
});

$('.circlechart').circlechart(); // Initialization
```

Comment: after the animation start and user scroll down further where this upload progress bar is not visible, should animation stop or once it began showing animation it should continue till it reaches 100%.

Comment: I only want that when user scroll down to middle section only then animation starts @Sandeep Garg

Comment: This is clear when to start the animation, I wanted to know after the animation starts, and meanwhile progress bar began to fill, and in the meantime, if user scrolls up or down such that the progress bar is now not visible, the animation needs to stop where it was or it should continue progressing

Comment: then animation needs to stop @Sandeep Garg

Answer (score 0):

Checkout answer of [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)
With reference to answer of Dan, I am adding code that you can use to start/stop animation of circular progress bar

```
function onVisibilityChange(el, callback) {
    var old_visible;
    return function () {
        var visible = isElementInViewport(el);
        if (visible != old_visible) {
            old_visible = visible;
            if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback(visible);
            }
        }
    }
}
var percentage = 0;
var handler = onVisibilityChange(el, function(visiblity_status) {
    /* your code go here */
    if (visibility_status) {
     if (percentage == 0) {
       $('.circlechart').circlechart(); 
     } else {
        // Code to resume progress bar if there is any method defined for the plugin you are using.
     }

    } else {
        // Code to stop progress bar if there is any method to stop it.
    }
});


//jQuery
$(window).on('DOMContentLoaded load resize scroll', handler);
```

Comment: did u implement `isElementInViewport` function written in reference answer of Dan I gave in answer.

Comment: Please check [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVgzRa?editors=1111) I have created. With this reference you can get some help in achieving what you want.

Comment: @ Sandeep Garg it wroks good but when you scroll up and down it copied the text. Please check screenshot https://nimb.ws/Xf28sv